# I have a fatal error with AsyncTask android

Tags: java, android, json, phpmyadmin

I am trying to take my data from database(phpmyadmin) and convert it to json to put it in `ListView` or `TextView` but when I run the application it close and when I check the log I found an exception.

this my code :

MainActivity.java

```
public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity {

ProgressDialog pDialog;
// Creating JSON Parser object

ListView lv;
ArrayList<HashMap<String, String>> productsList;

// url to get all products list
private static String url_all_products = "http://192.168.0.100/takeofftravel/test.php";
// products JSONArray
JSONArray products = null;
int error=0;
// JSON Node names
private static final String TAG_SUCCESS = "success";
private static final String TAG_NOTIF = "notif";
private static final String TAG_PID = "id";
private static final String TAG_Type = "type";
private static final String TAG_REQUETE = "requete";
@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
    // Hashmap for ListView.
    productsList = new ArrayList<HashMap<String, String>>();
    // Get listview
    lv = (ListView)findViewById(R.id.listView);
    // Loading products in Background Thread
    new LoadAllProducts().execute();



    // on seleting single product
    // launching Edit Product Screen
    lv.setOnItemClickListener(new AdapterView.OnItemClickListener() {

        @Override
        public void onItemClick(AdapterView<?> parent, View view,
                                int position, long id) {
  /*          HashMap<String,String> map=new HashMap<String, String>();
            map=(HashMap<String,String>)lv.getAdapter().getItem(position);
            String ide=map.get(TAG_PID);
            Toast.makeText(All.this,ide,Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
            Intent i=new Intent(getApplicationContext(),Detail.class);
            i.putExtra("id",ide);
            startActivity(i);
            finish();*/
        }
    });

}



class LoadAllProducts extends AsyncTask<String, String, String> {

    /**
     * Before starting background thread Show Progress Dialog
     * */
    @Override
    protected void onPreExecute() {
        super.onPreExecute();

        pDialog = new ProgressDialog(MainActivity.this);
        pDialog.setMessage("Loading...");
        pDialog.setIndeterminate(false);
        pDialog.setCancelable(false);
        pDialog.show();
    }

    /**
     * getting All products from url
     * */
    protected String doInBackground(String... args) {
        // Building Parameters
        HashMap<String, String> params = new HashMap<String, String>();
        JSONParser jParser = new JSONParser();
        // getting JSON string from URL

        JSONObject json = jParser.makeHttpRequest(url_all_products, "GET", params);

        // Check your log cat for JSON reponse
        Log.d("All Products: ", json.toString());






        // Checking for SUCCESS TAG
        int success = 0;
        try {
            success = json.getInt(TAG_SUCCESS);
            if (success == 1) {
                // products found
                // Getting Array of Products
                products = json.getJSONArray(TAG_NOTIF);

                // looping through All Products
                for (int i = 0; i < products.length(); i++) {
                    JSONObject c = products.getJSONObject(i);

                    // Storing each json item in variable
                    String id = c.getString(TAG_PID);
                    String type = c.getString(TAG_Type);
                    String requete=c.getString(TAG_REQUETE);

                    // creating new HashMap
                    HashMap<String, String> map = new HashMap<String, String>();

                    // adding each child node to HashMap key => value
                    map.put(TAG_PID, id);
                    map.put(TAG_Type, type);
                    map.put(TAG_REQUETE,requete);

                    // adding HashList to ArrayList
                    productsList.add(map);
                }
            } else {
            }
        } catch (JSONException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }



        return null;
    }

    /**
     * After completing background task Dismiss the progress dialog
     * **/
    protected void onPostExecute(String file_url) {
        // dismiss the dialog after getting all products
        pDialog.dismiss();
        // updating UI from Background Thread
        //    runOnUiThread(new Runnable() {
        //       public void run() {
        /**
         * Updating parsed JSON data into ListView
         * */
        ListAdapter adapter = new SimpleAdapter(
                MainActivity.this, productsList,
                R.layout.item, new String[] { TAG_PID,
                TAG_Type,TAG_REQUETE},
                new int[] { R.id.pid, R.id.nom,R.id.nature });
        // updating listview
        lv.setAdapter(adapter);
        //  }
        // });

    }

}
```

}

JSONParse.java file:

```
public class JSONParser {
String charset = "UTF-8";
HttpURLConnection conn;
DataOutputStream wr;
StringBuilder result;
URL urlObj;
JSONObject jObj = null;
StringBuilder sbParams;
String paramsString;

public JSONObject makeHttpRequest(String url, String method,
                                  HashMap<String, String> params) {

    sbParams = new StringBuilder();
    int i = 0;
    for (String key : params.keySet()) {
        try {
            if (i != 0){
                sbParams.append("&");
            }
            sbParams.append(key).append("=")
                    .append(URLEncoder.encode(params.get(key), charset));

        } catch (UnsupportedEncodingException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
        i++;
    }

    if (method.equals("POST")) {
        // request method is POST
        try {
            urlObj = new URL(url);

            conn = (HttpURLConnection) urlObj.openConnection();

            conn.setDoOutput(true);

            conn.setRequestMethod("POST");

            conn.setRequestProperty("Accept-Charset", charset);

            conn.setReadTimeout(10000);
            conn.setConnectTimeout(15000);

            conn.connect();

            paramsString = sbParams.toString();

            wr = new DataOutputStream(conn.getOutputStream());
            wr.writeBytes(paramsString);
            wr.flush();
            wr.close();

        } catch (IOException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
    }
    else if(method.equals("GET")){
        // request method is GET

        if (sbParams.length() != 0) {
            url += "?" + sbParams.toString();
        }

        try {
            urlObj = new URL(url);

            conn = (HttpURLConnection) urlObj.openConnection();

            conn.setDoOutput(false);

            conn.setRequestMethod("GET");

            conn.setRequestProperty("Accept-Charset", charset);

            conn.setConnectTimeout(15000);

            conn.connect();

        } catch (IOException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }

    }

    try {
        //Receive the response from the server
        InputStream in = new BufferedInputStream(conn.getInputStream());
        BufferedReader reader = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(in));
        result = new StringBuilder();
        String line;
        while ((line = reader.readLine()) != null) {
            result.append(line);
        }

        Log.d("JSON Parser", "result: " + result.toString());

    } catch (IOException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }

    conn.disconnect();

    // try parse the string to a JSON object
    try {
        jObj = new JSONObject(result.toString());
    } catch (JSONException e) {
        Log.e("JSON Parser", "Error parsing data " + e.toString());
    }

    // return JSON Object
    return jObj;
}
```

}

the error message:

```
E/AndroidRuntime: FATAL EXCEPTION: AsyncTask #1
              Process: com.example.asus.json, PID: 11657
              java.lang.RuntimeException: An error occured while executing doInBackground()
                  at android.os.AsyncTask$3.done(AsyncTask.java:300)
                  at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.finishCompletion(FutureTask.java:355)
                  at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.setException(FutureTask.java:222)
                  at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.run(FutureTask.java:242)
                  at android.os.AsyncTask$SerialExecutor$1.run(AsyncTask.java:231)
                  at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1112)
                  at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:587)
                  at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:841)
               Caused by: java.lang.NullPointerException
                  at com.example.asus.json.JSONParser.makeHttpRequest(JSONParser.java:124)
                  at com.example.asus.json.MainActivity$LoadAllProducts.doInBackground(MainActivity.java:100)
                  at com.example.asus.json.MainActivity$LoadAllProducts.doInBackground(MainActivity.java:75)
                  at android.os.AsyncTask$2.call(AsyncTask.java:288)
                  at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.run(FutureTask.java:237)
                  at android.os.AsyncTask$SerialExecutor$1.run(AsyncTask.java:231) 
                  at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1112) 
                  at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:587) 
                  at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:841)
```

Answer (score 0):

The main problem is with your JSONParser class at line 124. This is happening as JSONParser class is not returning any JSON and the resulting JSON is null and you are calling the function getInt() on the null JSON object, that is why the NullPointerException.

Comment: So what i should to do ?

Comment: You should try to make a Toast for result.toString() and check whether it shows something.